# Spark: How to delete a specific variable from spark-shell memory namespace?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using `spark-shell` and Scala. Is it possible to delete a variable from the shell's memory namespace?

For example, if I create variables like this:

```
val foo = 1
var bar = 2
```

Would it be possible to delete `foo` and `bar` from memory?

I know that in Python (using `del`) and R (using `rm`), you can delete specific variables from the namespace (aka environment or workspace).

Comment: assuming you're simplifying the question, and I think it depends on what you want to delete.  see comment below the one answer below.  so if you're trying delete an RDD instead of an Int...   and if you've created other RDDs from the RDD you want to delete...  i think you might be better served caching the subsequent RDD and .unpersist() the original.  i.e. `val rdd = ???; val rdd2 = rdd.map(???).cache; rdd.unpersist()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot delete a specific variable in Scala REPL.[1] What you can do is assigning a new value to override an existing variable. Scala REPL also provides a command `:reset` to remove all variables.

[1] Investigating memory leaks in the Spark Shell: https://gist.github.com/dragos/77b048c2baba93d36cd8

Comment: does assigning a new value accomplish the goal though?  see this example:  `val x=1; def xx=x+1; val x=99; print(xx)`  even after assigning a new value to x, the repl is hanging onto the old val x to evaluate def xx, so now if you defined anything else in terms of x, you're hanging on to both the old and new values for x?  if x were an RDD, or anything large, and you used it to build any other variables, I think this might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: 1. You cannot define the same variable in the same command. 2. Reassigning in a different command will keep both the old and new value in the memory.

Comment: the original question was about deleting variables...  my use-case that turned up this question was specifically about deleting RDDs...  but if anything has referenced the original, assigning a new value will keep both, which probably doesn't accomplish the goal since not many variables are defined in isolation.  in my case, I thought .unpersist() would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to.  I'm forced to stage data to S3, restart the shell and read it back in to have memory clean.  (re the same command issue, that was supposed to be 4 commands, but maybe better convention to put in comments?)

Comment: RDD.unpersist will remove data blocks of this RDD from memory and disk. The RDD itself will still be kept in the memory, but its memory usage should be little.